# R group bar plot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I need a group bar plot that looks as:

[image]

with an example data set like this:

```
   With IT background, No IT background
   9,1
   2,10
   7,1
   2,0
```

I tried to do it with `ggplot` but couldn't get any workable solutions

Comment: care to make a reproducible example? use dput() to make your dataset available and post what you have tried already.

Comment: +1 on sharing a reproducible example. In general, you can use `facet_wrap` [link](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html) to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't have any working code, therefore posting what I have won't help

Comment: I don't see the variables on the x axis in your example data

Comment: The example data is produced manually, the format is not important right now, I just need to produce the exact above group bar plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the code below. I strongly agree with the above commenters, please always make you code reproducible and provide the data if you ask for help. In this case it took me a minute to replicate your dataframe, but imagine you had 200 values?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
#recreate the data frame
data<- data.frame(With.IT.background=c(9,2,7,2), 
              No.IT.background=c(1,10,1,0))
#attach rownames
rownames(data)<- c("Aware of Risks", 
               "Not Aware of Risks", 
               "Care About", "Do Not Care About")
#make rownames a column (dplyr does not send rownames through pipe)
data %>% mutate(Awareness=rownames(data)) -> data

data %>% melt() %>% ggplot(data=., mapping=aes(x=Awareness, 
                               y=value, fill=Awareness)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme_bw() + 
    theme(axis.text.x= element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
    ylab("Answers") + xlab("With IT Background") +
    facet_wrap(~variable) +xlab("")
```

Comment: But the received plots are two single ones with two legends, isnt' it possible to receive only one plot like the above one?

Comment: yeah, you can do facet wrap

Comment: add library(reshape2)
and then plot in one line
data %>% melt() %>% ggplot(data=., mapping=aes(x=Awareness, 
                                   y=value, fill=Awareness)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme_bw() + 
        theme(axis.text.x= element_text(hjust=1, angle=45))+ ylab("Answers") +
        xlab("With IT Background") + facet_wrap(~variable) +xlab("")

Comment: Great thx it worked, could you also please tell me how to remove the labels on the x-Axis since it's the same as in the legend already?

Comment: btw, the edit from user1945827 is truly brilliant. I guess I assumed we were to do this in `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer in base R,

```
IT_data  <- data.frame(c(9,2,7,2),
                       c(1,10,1,0))
colnames(IT_data)  <- c("With IT background","No IT background")
rownames(IT_data)  <- c("Aware of Risks","Not Aware of Risks","Care About","Do Not Care About")

barplot(as.matrix(IT_data), beside=TRUE,
        col=rainbow(4),
        legend.text=rownames(IT_data), args.legend=list(x="topleft"))
```

The position and size of the legend can be improved with the following code,

```
barplot(as.matrix(IT_data), beside=TRUE,
        col=rainbow(4),
        legend.text=rownames(IT_data), args.legend=list(x="center",cex=0.7,bty="n"))
```

which is closer to the OP's request.

Answer (score 0):

Data for the exemple

```
Answers <- c(1,10,1,0, 9,2,7,2)
IT <- c(rep("With.IT.background",4), rep("No.IT.background",4))
Risks <- c("Aware of risks", "Not aware of risks", "Care about", "Do not care about")
data <- data.frame(cbind(IT, Risks, Answers))
```

Changing column types

```
data$Answers <- as.numeric(as.character(data$Answers))
data$Risks <- factor(data$Risks, levels = c("Aware of risks","Not aware of risks", "Care about", "Do not care about"))
```

And plot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(Risks), y=Answers, fill=factor(Risks))) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(. ~ IT) + 
      ggtitle("Awareness and risks") + guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) +
      labs(x = "") + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) + # remove xlab and tickers
      theme(legend.position=c(.5,.7)) +          # put the legend inside
      theme(legend.background=element_blank()) + # Remove overall border
      theme(legend.key=element_blank())          # Remove border around each item
```

Comment: It seems like the scales from the two plots are overlapping, on the x-Axis I get a scale starting with 9,7,2,10,1,0 ??

Comment: Fixed it and improved.